# Azure Webjobs 3.0 read from blob with manual trigger

Tags: .net, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have an Azure Webjob that processes a blob anytime it's changed:

```
        public async Task DoSomethingWithABlob(
            [BlobTrigger("myfiles/{filename}")] Stream blob,
            string filename)
        {
            //Process blob..
        }
```

This works fine, but I also want to manually trigger the processing of the blob on startup. Is there a way to do this?

I'm using Azure Webjobs SDK 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding , you have a continuous blob trigger webjob which used for monitoring a blob. And now you want to run your webjob once to do something on this webjob startup. But your webjob will not be triggered if there is no update on the blob that you want to monitor.

The way to implement it is creating another manually trigger webjob to do the things you need and start the continuous blob trigger webjob then.Just as below : 
[image]
ConsoleApp 12 is a C# console app which used for doing the processes you need and after the process is finished ,start the continuous blob trigger webjob. I write a sample for you :

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

             var containerName = "<your container name>";
             var blobName = "<blob name>";
             var StorageConnStr = "<storage account connection string>";


             CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(StorageConnStr);
             var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
             var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
             var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            //after get the blob , do your custom work here..




            //With all work is done ,start blobtriggerd webjob to monitor this blob
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                String userName = "<webapp user name>";
                String passWord = "<webapp password>";

                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, passWord);

                string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ":" +passWord));
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " +credentials;
                var response = client.UploadData("<webhook url which end with start>", "POST", new byte[0]) ;

                var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
            }



        }
    }
}
```

You can find webhook url , username and password here : 
[image]

**There is one thing that you should know that you should change your webhook url end with start as :**

```
https://<your app name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs/<your webjob name>/start
```

**instead of the original webhook which end with `run` :**

```
https://<your app name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs/<your webjob name>/run
```

as continuous webjobs have no run function.

This is the result that if I trigger the webjob manually : 
as you can see the work as been done(output blob content here for demo) and another continuous webjob has been started and it works perfectly for me .
[image]
[image]

Hope it helps.